# JSDoc an Array from Promise.All

Tags: node.js, types, promise, jsdoc

I try to document a Promise.all result as the type get lost once I destructured the data.

Here is an example, (I tried to trick it putting the promise inside a closure)

```js
      const promiseAll = () => {
        return Promise.all([
          this.b2bCompanies.getCompany(companyId, token),
          this.b2BFacade.getProfile(profileId, token),
        ]);
      };

      const [company, profile] = await promiseAll();
```

The original code is:

```js
      const [company, profile] = await Promise.all([
        this.b2bCompanies.getCompany(companyId, token),
        this.b2BFacade.getProfile(profileId, token),
      ]);
```

The company and profile become `*` but the `this.b2bCompanies.getCompany` returns a `CompanySchema` and the profile call a `ProfileSchema`

Any Idea how I can accomplish this and keep the code typed properly?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The [ES6 externs for Closure Compiler](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/externs/es6.js) defines [Promise.all](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/externs/es6.js#L1180) this way;

```
/**
 * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
 * @param {!Iterable<VALUE>} iterable
 * @return {!Promise<!Array<RESULT>>}
 * @template VALUE
 * @template RESULT := mapunion(VALUE, (V) =>
 *     cond(isUnknown(V),
 *         unknown(),
 *         cond(isTemplatized(V) && sub(rawTypeOf(V), 'IThenable'),
 *             templateTypeOf(V, 0),
 *             cond(sub(V, 'Thenable'), unknown(), V))))
 * =:
 */
Promise.all = function(iterable) {};
```

While I think defining it this way would work, I wonder if you could just include this externs? Of course that only makes sense if you're using Closure Compiler.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate but it looks very complicated :(